# How to convert Rows to JSON inside foreachPartition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to convert Row to JSON inside foreachPartition?
I have looked at [How to convert Row to json in Spark 2 Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601874/how-to-convert-row-to-json-in-spark-2-scala) .
However this approach won't work as I can't access sqlContext from within foreachPartition and also my data contains nested type.

```
 dataframe.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>

    ..
    val connectionString: ConnectionStringBuilder = new ConnectionStringBuilder(
                eventHubsNamespace,
                eventHubName,
                policyName,
                policyKey)

    val eventHubsClient: EventHubClient = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString.toString()).get()

    val json = /* CONVERT partitionOfRecords to JSON */

    val bytes = json.getBytes()
    val eventData = new EventData(bytes)
    eventHubsClient.send(eventData)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend doing the conversion to JSON **before** `foreachPartition`.

The reason is that there's the built-in support for JSON in `functions` object that you can use to build "stringified" JSONs using `to_json` function (without reverting to quite involved coding).

> **to_json(e: Column): Column** Converts a column containing a `StructType` or `ArrayType` of `StructTypes` into a JSON string with the specified schema.

I'd recommend doing the following:

```
dataframe.
  select(to_json($"your-struct-column-here")).
  as[String].
  foreachPartition { json: String => ... }
```