# Write a Spark streaming Dataframe into MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Streaming `Dataset` in Spark with a certain schema. When I want to compute a query on it I call:

```
StreamingQuery query = querydf
                      .writeStream()
                      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
                      .format("console")
                      .start();           

query.awaitTermination();
```

In this way I can see in the console the result of the query every trigger. How can I write the result DataFrame in Mongo? For Straming `Dataset` is not possible. Should I convert the streaming `Dataset` into static `Dataset` every trigger and then save it? How can I do it?

Comment: Is it possible to use the MongoSpark.save(..) method with structured streaming?

Comment: It is not. `RDDs` are not exposed with Structured Streaming.

Comment: That's true... I can't find any Java example on ForEachWriter implementation. Do you have any?

Comment: Java docs provide a template (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/ForeachWriter.html)

Comment: I seen that but I don't know how to configure in the proper way... how to insert the row of the dataframe in the mongodb?

Comment: The same as you'd do it using plain Java program using [Java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver)

Comment: Yes, but the Row has only the field values and not the key-value pairs like a JSON document... so how can I write into the mongodb in the process section in the right key-value pair format?

Comment: [Spark Row to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36157810/8371915)

Comment: Sure, this with static Dataframe, I have streaming dataframe and when implementing ForEachWriter I have to implement 3 functions: open, process and close, where process take as input a Row... so I cannot work with the entire dataframe but at row-level

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `MongoDbSink`:

```
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Sink
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.{DataSourceRegister, StreamSinkProvider}
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext}

class MongoDbSink(options: Map[String, String]) extends Sink with Logging {

  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = synchronized {
    val schema = data.schema
    val rdd = data.queryExecution.toRdd.mapPartitions { rows =>
      val converter = CatalystTypeConverters.createToScalaConverter(schema)
      rows.map(converter(_).asInstanceOf[Row])
    }

    // write RDD to MongoDB!!
  }
}

class MongoDbSinkProvider extends StreamSinkProvider with DataSourceRegister {
  def createSink(sqlContext: SQLContext,
                 parameters: Map[String, String],
                 partitionColumns: Seq[String],
                 outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {
    new MongoDbSink(parameters)
  }

  def shortName(): String = "my-mongo-sink"
}
```

And then implement the write to MongoDb how you like.

In the `.format()` of writeStream specify the path to the `MongoDbSinkProvider`