# How to set the property name when converting an array column to json in spark? (w/o udf)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with a fixed size array column. Like this:

```
[v1, v2, v3, v4]
```

I need to convert the array to a json of the following structure:

```
{ 
   v1: {
          Min: v2,
          Max: v3,
          Count: v4
   }
}
```

While it is easy to achieve to inner structure, having `v1` as the *name* of the property is more challenging.

I tried `'to_json'` but the keys are taken from column names. In my case `'v1'` changes in each row.

Is it possible to achieve this in pyspark without using a udf?
If it helps, I am running on top of Databricks.

Comment: My current approach is inspired by [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36167904/180650), where I construct the json by concatenation. Hopefully as time goes by we will have better primitives for this.