# Convert SQL output to JSON using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL query (using Scala as the language) which gives output as the following table where {name, type, category} is unique. Only type has limited values (due to 5-6 unique types).

| name | type | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | type1 | cat1 | value1 |
| First | type1 | cat2 | value2 |
| First | type1 | cat3 | value3 |
| First | type2 | cat1 | value1 |
| First | type2 | cat5 | value4 |
| Second | type1 | cat1 | value5 |
| Second | type1 | cat4 | value5 |

I'm looking for a way to convert it into a JSON with Spark such that output is something like this, basically get the output for every name & type combination.

```
[
  {
    "name": "First",
    "type": "type1",
    "result": {
      "cat1": "value1",
      "cat2": "value2",
      "cat3": "value3"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "First",
    "type": "type2",
    "result": {
      "cat1": "value1",
      "cat5": "value4"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Second",
    "type": "type1",
    "result": {
      "cat1": "value5",
      "cat4": "value5"
    }
  }
]
```

Is this possible via Spark scala? Any pointers or references would be really helpful.
Eventually I have to write the JSON output to S3, so if this is possible during write then it will also be okay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Row to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157810/spark-row-to-json)

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupBy`, `collect_set` then finally `map_from_entries` as below:

```
df = df
  .groupBy("name", "type")
  .agg(collect_set(struct("category", "value")).as("result"))
  .withColumn("result", map_from_entries(col("result")))
```

Exporting as JSON, however, will not give you the result as you expect. To get the expected result, you can use:

```
df.toJSON.collect.mkString("[", "," , "]" )
```

Final result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "First",
    "type": "type1",
    "result": {
      "cat3": "value3",
      "cat1": "value1",
      "cat2": "value2"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "First",
    "type": "type2",
    "result": {
      "cat1": "value1",
      "cat5": "value4"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Second",
    "type": "type1",
    "result": {
      "cat1": "value5",
      "cat4": "value5"
    }
  }
]
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm curious, why wouldn't `df.write.format("json").save("output.json")` work?

Comment: Because Spark writes to JSON in a format that it can read (it can infer schema)